# Don't get GIPHY api result?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fetch-api

when I try to hit my Giphy API,I don't get any result, don't know where I am wrong, please try to fix my error . If anyone have any doubt free feel to ask.

[image: Gif Result]

Get an response like this but I want actual Gif results.

```
const gifResponse  = async()=>{
    const result = await fetch("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending",{
      params:{
        api_key:"oatHPgj6zKaAMcxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    });
    console.log(result);
}

useEffect(()=>{
  gifResponse();
})
```

Comment: So you have response printed in console, so it means it's working. Maybe you should also wait for `gifResponse`?

Comment: @Justinas I need actual GIPHY Data..

Comment: Oh, I see. You do not return anything from your `gifResponse`

Comment: @Justinas Can you write the code?

Comment: `gifResponse = async() => {const [... rest of your code ...] return result;}`

Comment: @Justinas I did Changes, But I still getting Same Response